# HICON loaded with Gdiplus from PNG has low quality

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, imagelist

I am trying to load a few PNG images into an WinAPI `ImageList`, as icons for the elements to show in a `ListView`. I do this with `Gdiplus` and the problem I have is that the quality is awful. Is like the color depth is reduced or something.

This is how I do it (in a function called from `WinMain`, just before the loop):

```
HIMAGELIST hLarge;
HIMAGELIST hSmall;

hLarge = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON),
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON),
    ILC_MASK, 1, 1);

hSmall = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
    ILC_MASK, 1, 1);

ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hLarge, LVSIL_NORMAL);
ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hSmall, LVSIL_SMALL);

HICON hIconItem
Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(image_path, 0);
bitmap->GetHICON(&hIconItem);
ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hiconItem);
ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hiconItem);
```

Now, what am I missing and where does the image loose information?

[image: This is how icons show up and below the real icons (in PNG)]

I have changed `ILC_MASK` to `ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR32`. The quality is a little better but there's no anti-alias.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only `ILC_MASK` is not the correct flags to use for the type of image list that you want out of `ImageList_Create()`, but I'm not entirely sure. Can you post some images showing what you mean? (That is, show both the image and what you see in your listview.)

Comment: Added an image. The internet explorer icon looks looks so bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PNG is very likely 32-bit color. In your `ImageList_Create()` calls, use the flags `ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK`, not `ILC_MASK` only.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you don't specify one of the `ILC_COLORxxx` flags, it defaults to `ILC_COLOR4`, which is 4-bit 16 color graphics. This explains your reduced image quality. Explicitly specifying `ILC_COLOR32` will give you the full-color icons you want.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that improved the quality. Now, the icons are aliased and still look bad enough. Is there any simple anti-aliasing technique I could apply? It looks like the semi-transparent areas are not drawn (like the shadow of the VirtualBox icon)

Comment: I'm not sure. You can try omitting `ILC_MASK`, but if that doesn't work I wouldn't know.

Comment: That will replace the transparent areas with white (the shadows will be drawn tough). I have found something at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/76092-adding-bitmaps-with-semi-transparency-to-imagelist/ but that's another language

Comment: You do not use a mask with 32-bit bitmaps. This is what is causing @ali's problem. You would therefore specify only `ILC_COLOR32` (omitting `ILC_MASK`). Also, if you want to load an icon, call the `LoadImage` function with `IMAGE_ICON`. Skip the use of GDI+'s Bitmap class. That conversion is just going to introduce artifacts into the image.